# Tensorflow model accuracy low

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

So my main goal is to use data from 2018 and try to predict data for 2019. I'm using a GRU model and I have the following code. I have a few issues, I'm not sure if the code is actually correct or if I am missing something, and also for model.fit should I use validation_split=0.1 or validation_data=X_test,y_test since I'm using a different dataframe for tesing.

Regarding the accuracy, it is very small and doesn't make any sense and I have no idea why.

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.layers.core import Dense
from keras.layers.recurrent import GRU
from keras.models import Sequential
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from tensorboardcolab import TensorBoardColab, TensorBoardColabCallback


df = pd.read_csv('IF 10 PERCENT.csv',index_col=None)



#Loading Second Dataframe


df2 = pd.read_csv('2019 10minutes IF 10 PERCENT.csv',index_col=None)


tbc=TensorBoardColab() # Tensorboard




X_train= df[['WindSpeed_mps','AmbTemp_DegC','RotorSpeed_rpm','RotorSpeedAve','NacelleOrientation_Deg','MeasuredYawError','Pitch_Deg','WindSpeed1','WindSpeed2','WindSpeed3','GeneratorTemperature_DegC','GearBoxTemperature_DegC']]
X_train=X_train.values

y_train= df['Power_kW']
y_train=y_train.values

X_test= df2[['WindSpeed_mps','AmbTemp_DegC','RotorSpeed_rpm','RotorSpeedAve','NacelleOrientation_Deg','MeasuredYawError','Pitch_Deg','WindSpeed1','WindSpeed2','WindSpeed3','GeneratorTemperature_DegC','GearBoxTemperature_DegC']]
X_test=X_test.values

y_test= df2['Power_kW']
y_test=y_test.values

# conversion to numpy array



# scaling values for model


x_scale = MinMaxScaler()
y_scale = MinMaxScaler()

X_train= x_scale.fit_transform(X_train)
y_train= y_scale.fit_transform(y_train.reshape(-1,1))
X_test=x_scale.fit_transform(X_test)
y_test=y_scale.fit_transform(y_test.reshape(-1,1))



X_train = X_train.reshape((-1,1,12)) 
X_test = X_test.reshape((-1,1,12))


# splitting train and test




# creating model using Keras
model = Sequential()
model.add(GRU(units=512, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(1,12)))
model.add(GRU(units=256, return_sequences=True))
model.add(GRU(units=256))
model.add(Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss=['mse'], optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy']) 
model.summary() 

#model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=250, epochs=10, validation_split=0.1, verbose=1, callbacks=[TensorBoardColabCallback(tbc)])  
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=250, epochs=10, validation_data=(X_test,y_test), verbose=1, callbacks=[TensorBoardColabCallback(tbc)])

score = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
print('Score: {}'.format(score))
print('Accuracy: {}'.format(acc))
y_predicted = model.predict(X_test)
y_predicted = y_scale.inverse_transform(y_predicted)
y_t
est = y_scale.inverse_transform(y_test)
plt.plot(y_predicted, label='Predicted')
plt.plot(y_test, label='Measurements')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

It sounds to me that you are trying to solve a regression problem here. if it is so, It does not make sense to measure `accuracy` as a metric, since accuracy is about to measure the exact label matching. `MSE` should be pretty good for the regression

Comment: @alifter  So since I'm using different data for testing and training (2018 and 2019) it doesn't not make sense to use accuracy since they are not exactly the same? I'm extremely sorry this is my first ever model and I'm trying to understand everything that is going on.

Comment: No. Nothing to do with what's year data you use. Accuracy is good mostly for classification. Where the output is 0 or 1 ( for binary classification) , and you check to see if 1 is predicted as 1 and 0 as 0 or not. For regression, you wanna estimate a value, for example 1.52 , and you wanna check how close your approximation is. So if your model predicts 1.54 , MSE will give you 0.0004 but accuravy will give you 0. If your model predicts 1000, MSE will give you a loss of 10^6 , but accuracy still give you 0. Accurcay will be 1 in the case your model predict exactly 1.54

Comment: Ahhh okay this makes a lot of sense now! thank you very much! I'm deeply sorry but regarding the validation_split and validation_data, should I have it as Validation_split=0.1 for exmaple or validation_data= (X_test,y_test) since my testing data is a completely different csv file?

Comment: You re welcome. That is actually up to you how much you want to use the Validation. If you have enough resources, and it is separate from your training, I would go with it whole.

Comment: Sorry, for whole you mean both validation split and data, or just data? Also, does it make sense to have 'mse' for both loss and metrics? or loss as mse and metrics as mae?

Comment: I did not get the first part of your question. You have said Validation and training are separate. right? For the second question, it is really up to you. just be advised if you report mse or mae as the metric, you look forward for having a smaller number near to 0.  It is also important to know the differece between MSE and MAE. MSE is enlarging the errors. So if you do not have a uniformness of data, one big error beyond lots of small error still gives you very big error. However, you will have advangate to negligate the very small errors using MSE

Comment: So I'll show you both model.fit i have wrote to try and explain what I mean.

history=model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=512, epochs=2, validation_data=(X_test,y_test),validation_split=0.1, verbose=1, callbacks=[TensorBoardColabCallback(tbc)])

Or

history=model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=250, epochs=10, validation_split=0.1, verbose=1, callbacks=[TensorBoardColabCallback(tbc)])  

I have ran the code using both and I seems that both give me the same results. I ran only 10 epochs though and my MSE score was 8.8615e-4 , which I think is quite good?